# How to update large number of visuals in HelixViewport3D

Tags: c#, wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm developing a 3D viewer using the Helix 3D toolkit.  My scene can contain a large number of visuals, each with their own unique geometry that could potentially change all at once.  For example, I need to draw line that represent a rocket's flight path.  If I have hundreds of rockets flying at the same time, that would mean that the geometries of hundreds of flight paths would possibly be updated at the same time.  I'm assuming that my display would currently update each time a flight path's geometry changes, because I'm guessing that each visual is databound.

Ideally, I would love to refresh my display at a specified time as opposed to when each visual changes (i.e. change each visual in the background as updates come in and then refresh the scene at a specified time).  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to switch to use helix toolkit sharpdx version for better performance on line rendering. And use instancing for rocket rendering.